# Mac only booting into Ubuntu and not rEFInd

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, macbook-pro, 15.04, refind

I installed rEFInd on my Mid-2010 13-inch MBP and installed Ubuntu on another partition. The Mac does not boot into rEFInd to select OS X or Ubuntu, it only boots into Ubuntu. I can still access the data on my OS X partition from Ubuntu, but I can't boot into the OS X partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try holding down the Option (or Alt) key as you start up the computer. This should provide you with a menu you can use to select the OS to boot. Using that menu, boot to OS X. You can then re-install rEFInd. With any luck that will fix the problem.

If you continue to boot straight to Ubuntu, look for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode; if it's absent, you've booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. If you boot Ubuntu in EFI mode, you may be able to use `efibootmgr` to adjust the boot order -- but Macs are a bit weird and doing this may not work in quite the normal way.